# Continuous Gradle build

Tags: gradle, jhipster, gradlew

I'm a relatively new user with Gradle, I'm working for the first time on a project (and first time with JHipster as well).

To run my application through the terminal, I execute the following command:

```
gradlew.bat
```

But at each new modification I have to kill the application `ctrl + c` and run it again.

I already tried using the command `gradlew.bat -t build -x test` (I don't want to run test each time) and  `gradlew.bat --continue`, but both did not work.

Comment: The `build` task allows you to run the application ?

Comment: I tried to use `run`, but I can not match them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `bootRun` task, which is the default task gradle doesn't know when to start watching, so it is not possible with gradle only. Using your ide (e.g. intellij) and the springboot devtools it is possible.

- Start the application from our ide
- Make changes in the code
- In intellij press `ctrl` + `F9` to compile the code and the application should restart

When you want to do it with gradle only you need two terminals and start e.g. `javaCompile` in continuous mode and `bootRun` in another terminal. The boot devtools will take care of restarting the application when it detects the newly compiled files.

- `gradlew compileJava -t` in on terminal
- `gradlew bootRun` in another terminal